# How to load variables in a "bar=foo" syntax in CMake?

Tags: cmake, key-value

It is nice to be able to share the same file between a Makefile and shell scripts due to the fact that they both can cope with the following syntax for key-value pairs:

```
$> cat config 
  var1=value
  var2=value
  var3=value
  var4=value
  var5=value
```

So, just a `source config` from a shell script will be fine, as well as `include config` from a `Makefile`. However, with CMake the syntax becomes `SET(var1 value)`. Is there some easy way that I can feed CMake with a file with variables using the syntax of above? I mean easy in the sense that I do not like to run e.g. `sed` over it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@Guillaume's answer is ideal for generating a config file from within your CMakeLists.txt.

However, if you're looking to import the contents of a config file like this *into* your CMake environment, you'll need to add something like:

```
file(STRINGS <path to config file> ConfigContents)
foreach(NameAndValue ${ConfigContents})
  # Strip leading spaces
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^[ ]+" "" NameAndValue ${NameAndValue})
  # Find variable name
  string(REGEX MATCH "^[^=]+" Name ${NameAndValue})
  # Find the value
  string(REPLACE "${Name}=" "" Value ${NameAndValue})
  # Set the variable
  set(${Name} "${Value}")
endforeach()
```

Comment: I like this approach. It is not exactly 'easy', but it does not need dependencies such as `sed` which I did use upto now. I just didn't think of using regexp in cmake itself!

Comment: Well... it's good to have both answers in the one place.  It has symmetry :)

Answer (score 2):

With cmake 3.12 one can try something like this:

```
file(STRINGS config CONFIG REGEX "^[ ]*[A-Za-z0-9_]+[ ]*=")
list(TRANSFORM CONFIG STRIP)
list(TRANSFORM CONFIG REPLACE "([^=]+)=[ ]*(.*)" "set(\\1 \"\\2\")\n")
cmake_language(EVAL CODE ${CONFIG})

# just for test
message(STATUS "a=\"${a}\"")
message(STATUS "b=\"${b}\"")
```

Testing:

```
rion@dizzynb ~/temp $ cmake --trace -P test.cmake 
Running with trace output on.
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake(1):  file(STRINGS config CONFIG REGEX ^[ ]*[A-Za-z0-9_]+[ ]*= )
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake(2):  list(TRANSFORM CONFIG STRIP )
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake(3):  list(TRANSFORM CONFIG REPLACE ([^=]+)=[ ]*(.*) set(\\1 \"\\2\")\n )
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake(4):  cmake_language(EVAL CODE ${CONFIG} )
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake:4:EVAL(1):  set(a hello world )
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake:4:EVAL(2):  set(b 10 )
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake(6):  message(STATUS a=\"${a}\" )
-- a="hello world"
/home/rion/temp/test.cmake(7):  message(STATUS b=\"${b}\" )
-- b="10"

rion@dizzynb ~/temp $ cat config 
# this is my config
a=hello world
 b = 10 
#c= O_o
```

But keep in mind the eval above may be unreliable for some contents.

Comment: But will a change in the "config" file than trigger a cmake run?
I'm not sure that this happens automatically by all files that are read via file.

Comment: @Lothar, I believe cmake custom target with a dependency on the config file should do the trick. 
In any case only the topic starter knows if he is going to change his config at all.

Answer (score 1):

Create a config.in file with all variables you want to "extract" of your CMakeLists:

```
var1=@VAR1@
var2=@VAR2@
var3=@VAR3@
var4=@VAR4@
var5=@VAR4@
```

and add a `configure_file` call in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config
    @ONLY
)
```

This will create a config file.

Comment: This answer does the opposite of what the asker wants: it exports cmake variables to a config file. The askers intention is to make variables from a "bash-style" file available in cmake.