# CMake use variables from file

Tags: c++, cmake

I'd like to share some variables between my scripts and CMake. It would be nice to re-use bash syntax:

```bash
var1=value1
var2=value2
...
```

I was trying to use the solution from here as the problem is pretty much the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17167673/15035275 But the solution didn't work for me.

I created a file `config.in` containing:

```bash
FOO=foobar
```

And I added this config file to my CMakeLists file:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config
        @ONLY
)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)


message(STATUS "foo is equal to: ${FOO}")

...
```

But the variable `${FOO}` isn't visible by CMake:

```bash
/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G Ninja -S /home/p -B /home/p/cmake-build-debug
-- foo is equal to: 
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
...
```

How can I use the variables from `config.in` ?

Comment: Is it ok to share variables from cmake to script (you have tried opsite direction)? How long is list variables which suppose to be shared? Who runs script which should have access to those variables?

Comment: Preferably I'd like to have a separate file with variables only, so I could use it both in bash and in CMake. But I have no idea how to import that file to CMake. The number of variables is ~15. All scripts in the directory should have access to these variables.

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate for the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165905/how-to-load-variables-in-a-bar-foo-syntax-in-cmake), which answer you have referenced. It happens that the answer you refer to is not correct (or is simply resolves some *other* problem than asked in the duplicate question). The other answers are still valid. E.g. the [accepted and most voted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168870/3440745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked is not applicable to your problem - I've left a comment on that answer as well.

I don't know of a generic way apart from the regex-based solutions offered by other people in the question you linked.

I can only give you a somewhat more verbose alternative, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712713/1480324):

```
execute_process(COMMAND ". config.in && echo -n $FOO" OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)
message(STATUS "FOO=${FOO}")
```

Comment: I think you can post as the solution to the original problem as IMHO it looks much cleaner than the most-voted answer there. Worked well for me with syntax: `execute_process(COMMAND bash -c ". config && echo -n $FOO" OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)`